# Approval-Test throws System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, approval-tests

I am trying to use Approval-Tests but can't even run "Hello World". When I run the test I get

```
Test Name:  TestHelloWorld
Test FullName:  HelloApprovalTests.Class1.TestHelloWorld
Test Source:    C:\Users\Lassi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloApprovalTests\HelloApprovalTests\Class1.cs : line 14
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.01

Result StackTrace:  
at ApprovalTests.Namers.UnitTestFrameworkNamer..ctor()
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.<.cctor>b__c()
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.GetDefaultNamer()
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.Verify(IApprovalWriter writer)
   at ApprovalTests.Approvals.Verify(String text)
   at HelloApprovalTests.Class1.TestHelloWorld() in C:\Users\Lassi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HelloApprovalTests\HelloApprovalTests\Class1.cs:line 15
Result Message: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Diagnostics.StackTrace ApprovalUtilities.CallStack.Caller.get_StackTrace()'.
```

My class is:

```
using ApprovalTests;
using ApprovalTests.Reporters;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace HelloApprovalTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    [UseReporter(typeof(DiffReporter))]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestHelloWorld()
        {
            Approvals.Verify("Hello World Welcome to ApprovalTests");
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to make this run and create a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something is odd on the Nuget install. If you update ApprovalUtilities it will work.

Comment: Somehow I had version 3.0.1. Updated to 3.0.11 and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: This is because of NuGet's default dependency behaviour, which is to install the lowest version of a depended-upon package.  As it looks likes  ApprovalTests 3.0.11 needs at least ApprovalUtilities 3.0.11 in order to work, it should probably be added to its manifest.

Comment: For general convenience, here's the Package Manager Console command to copy-paste and run:
Update-Package ApprovalUtilities -version 3.0.11